# Cant seem to be able to use sculpt tool in blender

Tags: sculpting

Cant seem to be able to use sculpt tool in blender. I'm following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yApJx_uM7TM&list=WL&index=7

I get stuck on the sculpting part for some reason it just does nothing I did subdivison and applied them to the parts before sculpting but I cant find any fix. my blender version is the latest.

"also says object has non-uniform scale "sculpting may be unpredictable"

Link to blend file:
https://blend-exchange.com/b/gDggqYy8

Before applying scale
[image: before]

After applying scale
[image]

This is what I get if I try to apply to cube 3 the other cubes/petals stay in the same place if I try to apply the curve modifier.
[image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146279/discussion-on-question-by-kess-elder-cant-seem-to-be-able-to-use-sculpt-tool-in); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Select one of your objects, let's say *Cube*, apply the *Subdivision Surface* modifier, apply the scale (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>), disable the *Array* in order to more easily see the original object, sculpt.

If you are in *Sculpt Mode* you can only sculpt on the selected object, if you want to switch to another object you need to either switch back to *Object* mode and select the other object, or press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> to select another object while in *Sculpt* mode (the new object will be lit when you'll put your cursor on it).